# How to make MS SQL Server return the number of miliseconds stored in a datetime field?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `datetime` field in my database, and I need to get the number of milliseconds since the epoch. I can calculate that on the client application, but my question is if there is a way to get it from the SQL server.

I tried this:

```
select cast(dateField as bigint) from table where id = 0
```

... but I get a 5 digit number that can't possibly be what I want.

Is that at all possible?

Comment: You're talking about converting to unix time?

Comment: @Martin Smith: I was thinking in milliseconds, but I would be happy with that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (for system date - modify to put your date in there):

```
SELECT cast(DATEDIFF(s, '19700101', GETDATE()) as bigint) * 1000
```

Comment: Should probably add `DATEPART(ms, datefield)` onto this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try

Select DATEPART(ms, datefield) FROM table where id=0

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

Comment: That only shows the millisecond portion, not total milliseconds since 0-day.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried... cast(datefield as bigint) ... but I get a five digit number

Sql Server stores datetimes as an 8-byte float value, where the integer portion is the number of whole days and the decimal portion is fractional days. Casting to any integral type will give you days, not milliseconds.

> I need to get the number of milliseconds since the epoch

What is your epoch? Sql Server uses 1/1/1900 (it will store negative values for dates prior to this), but many people expect 1/1/1970.

With all that in mind, you want one of the following:

```
DATEDIFF(millisecond, '19700101', datefield)
DATEDIFF(millisecond, 0, datefield)
```

Comment: It's actually stored as two `int` values concatenated together. One with number of days and the other with number of ticks. `SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(B,1, 4) AS INT) AS Days,CAST(SUBSTRING(B,5,4) AS INT) AS Ticks FROM (SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS BINARY(8))) T(B)`

Comment: Where a tick = 1/300th of a second. (This is specific to datetime ; datetime2 is totally different of course)

Comment: And the problem with `DATEDIFF(millisecond` is that this overflows unless the dates are in  a narrow range.

Answer (score 0):

```
select CONVERT (varchar(20), tdate,113) from tblTrainingMaster
```

Instead of

```
 select CONVERT (varchar(20), tdate,120) from tblTrainingMaster
```